# Can I set apart changes I did in Moodle core to plugin?

Tags: moodle

I have changed the source code in the /lib/coursecatlib.php file. Can I set apart this changes to plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes that can be made entirely withing plugins, by using the hooks made available in Moodle.

You haven't said what changes you have made to coursecatlib.php, but I suspect that anything you have done there will be hard/impossible to transfer into a plugin.

The closest you can get is usually to minimise the changes by adding a single line of code that calls a function in a custom plugin (preferably one in an [automatically loaded class](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Automatic_class_loading)).